# I am trying to Nested ListView like Listheader then Childheader then I want add in subchild in childlistview

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, listadapter

`Order_Content` - this is the page I want to show the nested listview. Here I Take input for The Header Data And Child Data from JSON Webservice. String res for Dropdown menu and All remaining Stings mov ,movpks, mus, muspks for listview.

When I click on MOVIE Then Show Zindagi melena dubara... all but when I click on Zindagi mile na dubara I want add "order" to each childlistview.

```
public class Order_Content  extends Activity{
    Spinner selectpkj;
    EditText Year,Banner,Producer,Director,Main_Cast,Genre,Music_Director;
    Button Search;

    /*String[] res = new String[] { "Movie", "Movie Packs", "Music",
            "Music Packs", "All" };*/
    String res;
    String mov;
    String movpks;
    String mus;
    String muspks;

    String Yeard,Bannerd,Producerd,Directord,Maisn_Castd,Genred,Music_Directord;



     //Deifine the all variable for the expandable platform **//
     ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
     ExpandableListView expListView;
     List<String> listDataHeader;
     HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.order_content);
        //*** Bind All Definer Layouts ***//
        selectpkj=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spselectmovie);
        Search =(Button)findViewById(R.id.serach);

        Year=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.year);
        Banner=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.banner);
        Producer=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.producer);
        Director=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.director);
        Main_Cast=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.maincast);
        Genre=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.genere);
        Music_Director=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.musicdirector);

        //*** Get EditText Value for search here ***//
        /*Yeard = Year.getText().toString();
        Bannerd = Banner.getText().toString();
        Producerd = Producer.getText().toString();
        Directord = Director.getText().toString();
        Maisn_Castd = Main_Cast.getText().toString();
        Genred = Genre.getText().toString();
        Music_Directord = Music_Director.getText().toString();
        */
        // *** Getting Contents form the last pages ***//
        String lcouserID = getIntent().getStringExtra("lcouserID");
        String SearchList = getIntent().getStringExtra("SearchList");
        String MOVIES = getIntent().getStringExtra("MOVIES");
        String MOVIESPACK = getIntent().getStringExtra("MOVIESPACK");
        String MUSIC = getIntent().getStringExtra("MUSIC");
        String MUSICPACK = getIntent().getStringExtra("MUSICPACK");

        res = SearchList;
        mov = MOVIES;
        movpks = MOVIESPACK;
        mus = MUSIC;
        muspks = MUSICPACK;



     // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

     // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

     // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

     // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


     // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


     // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)+ " : "+ listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });





        // *** Display Data into Spinner Successfully ***//
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(res.toString());
            // JSONArray array = new JSONArray(res.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                list.add(array.getString(i));
                System.out.println("I Position : " + array.getString(i));
                // System.out.println("List Output : " + list);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String myString = "Select to Search";
        String addatend ="All";
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //dataAdapter.addAll(myString);
                dataAdapter.insert(myString, 0);
                dataAdapter.add(addatend);
                selectpkj.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


                selectpkj.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        if (item.equals("Select to Search")){
                            invisible();
                            //Subscriber_Name.setText(null);
                        }else if (item.equals("MOVIE") || (item.equals("All"))) {
                            visible();

                        }else{
                            invisible();

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });





    }


//*** Preparing the list data method ***//

    private void prepareListData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        //*** Here logic for the add data in to MAIN LIST from response ***//
        final List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(res.toString());
            // JSONArray array = new JSONArray(res.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                list1.add(array.getString(i));
                System.out.println("I Position : " + array.getString(i));
                // System.out.println("List Output : " + list);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listDataHeader = list1;

     /*// Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Movie");
        listDataHeader.add("Movie Packs");
        listDataHeader.add("Music");
        listDataHeader.add("Music Packs");*/

         //*** Here logic for the add data in to MAIN LIST from response ***//
        final List<String> movi = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(mov.toString());
            // JSONArray array = new JSONArray(res.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                movi.add(array.getString(i));
                System.out.println("I Position : " + array.getString(i));
                // System.out.println("List Output : " + list);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250 = movi;
       /* top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
        top250.add("The Godfather");
        top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
        top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
        top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
        top250.add("The Dark Knight");
        top250.add("12 Angry Men");*/

        final List<String> movipacks = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(movpks.toString());
            // JSONArray array = new JSONArray(res.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                movipacks.add(array.getString(i));
                System.out.println("I Position : " + array.getString(i));
                // System.out.println("List Output : " + list);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing = movipacks;

        /*nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
        nowShowing.add("Turbo");
        nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");
        nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");*/


        final List<String> musi = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(mus.toString());
            // JSONArray array = new JSONArray(res.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                musi.add(array.getString(i));
                System.out.println("I Position : " + array.getString(i));
                // System.out.println("List Output : " + list);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon = musi;
        /*comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");*/


        final List<String> musipks = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(muspks.toString());
            // JSONArray array = new JSONArray(res.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                musipks.add(array.getString(i));
                System.out.println("I Position : " + array.getString(i));
                // System.out.println("List Output : " + list);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<String> musicpaks = new ArrayList<String>();
        musicpaks = musipks;
        /*musicpaks.add("2 Guns");
        musicpaks.add("The Smurfs 2");
        musicpaks.add("The Spectacular Now");
        musicpaks.add("The Canyons");
        musicpaks.add("Europa Report");*/



        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), musicpaks);



    }





//*** invisible method ***//
  protected void invisible() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Year.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Banner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Producer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Director.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Main_Cast.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Genre.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Music_Director.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



    }

    //*** Visible Method ***//
    public void visible() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Year.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Banner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Producer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Director.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Main_Cast.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Genre.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Music_Director.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        getdata();


    }


    public void getdata() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Yeard = Year.getText().toString();
        Bannerd = Banner.getText().toString();
        Producerd = Producer.getText().toString();
        Directord = Director.getText().toString();
        Maisn_Castd = Main_Cast.getText().toString();
        Genred = Genre.getText().toString();
        Music_Directord = Music_Director.getText().toString();

        Search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                 //prepareListData();

            }
        });

    }





}
```

Comment: Please don't write all bold text. Online communities take this as shouting and rude and it might deprive you of good answers. Plus, your question is kind of unclear. Please try to make it better understandable.

Comment: Ok Sir..please help me i am new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am getting you right, than what you want is something like an `ExpandableListview` inside another `ExpandableListview`. The requirement is tricky and solution is bit complicated.

Follow the bellow link. It demonstrates the 3-level expandable `ListView`.

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/02/3-level-expandable-lists.html

Mark as right, if this is what you are looking for. :)

Comment: Your welcome and if you can, vote up and Mark my as right . :)